# Is it possible to lose contact with a region on purpose?

Tags: xcom-2

I am in a bit of a pickle with my run through of the campaign.

I have already taken out the first black site and seem to be quite far into the tech tree as I don't have too much trouble with missions right now. However, I have procrastinated on taking out further advent facilities and now the avatar project has been finished, I am quite close to two other facilities but I am unable to make contact with their regions as I am full on contact spots.

I have about 12 days left in the countdown before game over. This means I am unable to complete the room that unlocks more contact spots because it will take like 15 days to build. On top of that, I don't have the necessary power for the building, and I have an upgraded power station with an engineer stationed there.

Is there a way to purposefully lose contact with one of my regions so I am able to gain contact with a region I actually need?

Comment: This does not directly answer the question, but do you have any spare engineers and/or the resources to upgrade a communication room?

Comment: That's the problem, I don't have a communications room. And it would take too long to build one

Comment: I can recall a few missions where the reward was one more contact slot.  I don't suppose you have any active like that right now?

Comment: No, I only have one for like some alien alloys or something

Comment: Is that 15 day build time with, or without an engineer assigned to speed up build time?

Comment: Without, but I don't have the necessary power for it either, and that is with an upgrade to the power generator and an engineer stationed there. So I'm pretty sure building the room is out of the question for now.

Comment: Though I do have an idea, this is probably better as a new question, but if I can unbuild a room to get the necessary power, I may be able to complete the communication room. But it depends on how long it takes to destroy a room.

Comment: Can you complete a skulljack objective? Those also turn back the doom clock.

Comment: Hm.... Maybe, I can't remember if I completed that yet

Comment: As a last resort, you can use console commands if you really don't want to start over

Comment: I would probably do that if I was farther in the game, but as it is, it's not too much of a problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can loose contact to a region, but not a chosen region as far as I know.

You have the following options:

- Complete a blacksite mission/shadow chamber mission, or blow up an avatar facility
- Complete the first skulljack mission (that is: jack in, kill the *thingy*)
- Complete the second skulljack mission (that is: jack in, kill the *scarrier thingy*)
- Fail to respond to the mission to rescue a civilian outpost (or fail the mission by any means). It will make the outpost "regroup", which will sever the contact with this region. Note that this is on a 6 week timer. It might not come around soon enough.
- Use skull mining on a soldier, and successfully get a facility lead. You must have no facility lead in storage. If you already had one in storage, what are you waiting for. Once you obtain one, you need to "research" it, then you attack the facility. The facility lead can also be a reward from hacking a "lamp post", but it seems quite rare.
- Complete a mission that has a contact slot as the reward. Then make contact.

No other missions have a way of reducing the avatar timer as far as I know.

Comment: Figures, I just completed a rescue civilian mission before I realized I couldn't contact the region I needed

Comment: While this technically didn't answer the specific question asked, it got to the root of the issue, which was the countdown timer. Thanks for the answer. What I ended up doing was dismantle one of the rooms, which was an instant action, then, using the freed up power was able to build a communications room fast enough with an engineer in it. All said and done, I ended up having 4 hours left on the timer when I started the mission. Cutting it a bit close, but I got it. lol

Comment: Additionally, if you research a facility lead while all current alien facilities known to you, the lead will allow you to attack a facility without having to contact the region it is in.

Comment: @Dulkan That is in fact the only benefit of facility leads -- as far as I know, they don't *add* facilities to the map.

Comment: Don't forget, you can also fail/refuse a council mission or supply raid.  Both of those cost you the region upon refuse/fail.  Please add to the list?  I thought about editing directly but seemed jerky.

Comment: Or a downed/landed UFO.